# Copy bits in correct order

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

In order to parse a binary stream of unmanaged data, I have to recreate data types. The data is compressed which means I read 2 bytes which actually represent a 6-bit `byte` value and a 10-bit `short` value.

All I need to do is copy a bit-sequence from one value to another. I know the start bit and length for the source value and the destination value. So far I have made two approaches which both copy the right bits but somehow in reverse order.

```
byte BitwiseCopy(short value, int sourceStartBit, int destStartBit, int bitCount)
{
    short result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bitCount; i++)
        //result |= (byte) (value & (1 << sourceStartBit + i) | (result & (1 << (destStartBit + bitCount) - i)));
        result |= (short) (value & (1 << sourceStartBit + i));

    return (byte) (result >> ((destStartBit - bitCount) + sizeof(byte) * 8));
}
```

For my test scenario I am using a short with the following value:

```
0000 0000 1101 0011
^15               ^0
```

My goal is to copy the *4-th* - *7-th* bit of this short to a byte's *0-3rd* bits.

When I use either the commented line (without the code in the return clause) approach or the way it's currently highlighted, I always get this result:

```
0000 1011
^7      ^0
```

So what I want, just reversed. I'm sure it's something tiny, but what am I overlooking here? I don't get why it reverses order. The bit-shifting approach (copying directly bitwise and shifting it to the correct position) shouldn't reverse it, should it?

**EDIT**:
The method **always** has an input of type `short`. I have 3 parameters: *sourceStart* which is the bit I start to copy from the input value (low to high), *destStart* which is the bit I copy to into my destination (which is either byte or short - I would make two specific methods for this) and *bitCount* which is the amount of bits (starting from low to high order) I want to copy.

The method **must** copy bits in correct order. So for example `CopyBitwise(input, 4, 0, 4)` should return (left: high, right: low order) `0000 1011` given this input:

```
input [short]: ... 1011 0110
                   ^8th    ^0th
```

Another one:

```
input [short]: 1011 0110 0100 0111
               ^15th             ^0th
                    ^end ^start
```

`CopyBitwise(input, 7, 3, 5)` should result in

```
0011 0000
^8th    ^0th
^end ^start
```

Comment: What exactly is your input and what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: The input is always a short which I have to split up into a byte and another short value. I want a generic method which takes *n* bytes starting at *sourceStart* from the input and copies it to a destination byte/short at *destStart* in the exact same sequence.

Comment: You should clearly list what the output byte and short should be for the given input value. I'm still unclear too. Add a few mores samples to avoid confusion.

Comment: Your code is not helping to explain, this should not require a for-loop.

Comment: Did you just step it through in the debugger, to see how your `result` changes with each iteration? And bommelding is right: Just use a mask, shift and cast.

Comment: 'unmanaged data' is not a real thing. Endian-ness in files is a major issue here. Be clear to show how you read this (reading a `short` or a `byte[2]` is not the same).

Comment: I am not sure how you are displaying your result - but I have just tested your method & the result I get is "00001101" - so appears to be working correctly (even though it could be improved) : https://dotnetfiddle.net/lhUt4J

Comment: Okay I added two more (more detailed) examples. Hope this helps to understand :) I did, but it's less easy to check without a binary visualization. I'll try the masking approach, that sounds like it could work (though I think this would be similiar to the one I have with direct copying and shifting).

Comment: @bommelding I am aware of this, but so far the endianess has proven to be correct with other data. I am working with a barely functional and incomplete protocol so I have to figure it out anyway. But it should be correct so far. Otherwise I'll keep that in mind and try that approach. Okay well, so then maybe my output is wrong for some reason... VS should be able to display values in binary as well

Comment: Is the expected answer to your last example correct. According to your rules you want 5 bits starting at bit 7 - this equals "01100", then you want this to start at bit three in the result - so there should be three more 0s to the right giving "01100000"

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a loop for that !
This should do the trick :

```
byte BitwiseCopy(short value, int sourceStartBit, int destStartBit, int bitCount){
    byte result = (byte) ((value >> sourceStartBit) << destStartBit);
    result &= (byte) ~(0xff << bitCount); // mask for zeros at the left of result
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Code that compiles is more likely to get upvotes & marked as correct. Otherwise an improved way of doing what OP wants.

Comment: Yes, definetly got to thank you. Since it's performance critical it's even better that way. Nonetheless PaulF is right, it does not compile this way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to cut out a sub-sequence of a given short. This can be achieved by *masking*. If you want to cut out the highlighted bits from of the following bit sequence: `1011 0110` ***`0100`*** `0111`, you can do so by `&`ing it with `0000 0000 1111 0000`.

```
  1011 0110 0100 0111
& 0000 0000 1111 0000
= 0000 0000 0100 0000
```

You can then shift the resulting bits, so that your masked bits start at the desired location (here 1):

```
  0000 0000 0100 0000 >>
 · 0000 0000 0100 000 >>
 ·· 0000 0000 0100 00 >>
 ··· 0000 0000 0100 0
```

---

### To make it more concrete, here is some code:

```cs
byte BitwiseCopy(short value, int sourceStartBit, int destStartBit, int bitCount)
{
    ushort mask = 0; //Start with 0
    mask = (ushort)~mask; //Invert to get all 1s
    mask >>= sizeof(ushort)*8 - bitCount; //Shift right, until we have bitCount bits left
    mask <<= sourceStartBit; //Shift back left, to make sure the bits are in the right place
    
    ushort result = (ushort)value;
    result &= mask; //Mask out the bits we want
    
    //Shift the remaining bits into the desired position
    if (sourceStartBit < destStartBit)
    {
        result <<= destStartBit - sourceStartBit;
    }
    else
    {
        result >>= sourceStartBit - destStartBit;
    }
    return (byte)result;
}
```

### Code Breakdown:

First, we assemble the bit mask. To do so, we start with `0`, and then invert all the bits to get all ones. We could start with `0xFFFF`, but this way the code will still work if you switch to a different-length input.

Then we shift our mask until there are only `bitCount` `1`s left. For this step, it is important that our mask is an *unsigned* integer type. If you were using a signed value, the bitshift would shift in new `1`s from the left.

To finish our mask, we shift it back left to position it correctly.

Next, we apply the mask to our value to cut out the bits we don't want.

Finally, we shift the result into the desired position; here it is again important to use *unsigned* shifts, to ensure no erroneous `1`s get shifted in from the left.

---

Here's an example of what happens when calling the method with the arguments
`(0b1011_0110_0100_0111, 7, 3, 5)`, as in your second example.

```
mask:
  0000 0000 0000 0000  ~x
= 1111 1111 1111 1111  x>>(16 - 5)
= 0000 0000 0001 1111  x<<7
= 0000 1111 1000 0000

result:
  1011 0110 0100 0111  x&mask
  0000 0110 0000 0000  x>>(7-3)
  0000 0000 0110 0000
```

**EDIT 1:**
Corrected this line `mask >>= bitCount - sizeof(ushort)*8;` in the code to `mask >>= sizeof(ushort)*8 - bitCount;`.

**EDIT 2:**
I had also messed up the line right below, fixed that too. That's what I get for only testing one case.

**EDIT 3:**
Added step-by-step Example.

Comment: Some C# code would have been useful here, but you haven't considered that if the source start bit is less than the destination start bit the data will need shifting left.

Comment: Did you test this to see if it gets the expected results from OPs examples

Answer (score 0):

This should work correctly.
First create a mask for the bits that you require then shift them into the required place. Note that the shift is done in two moves as the shift operator must be a positive number.

```
byte BitwiseCopy(short value, int sourceStartBit, int destStartBit, int bitCount)
{
  short mask = (short)((0xFFFF >> (16-bitCount)) << sourceStartBit);
  short result = (short)(((value & mask) >> sourceStartBit) << destStartBit);
  return (byte)result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the BitWiseCopy method from above so that you can copy bits not only into an empty/new byte, but also into an existing (destination).

In this example, I want to copy 3 bits (bitCount=3) from bit #4 (sourceStartBit) to bit #3 (destinationStartBit). Please note that the numbering of bits starts with "0" and that in my method, the numbering starts with the most significant bit = 0 (reading from left to right).

```
byte source = 0b10001110;
byte destination = 0b10110001;

byte result = CopyByteIntoByte(source, destination, 4, 1, 3);
Console.WriteLine("The binary result: " + Convert.ToString(result, toBase: 2));
//The binary result: 11110001

byte CopyByteIntoByte(byte sourceByte, byte destinationByte, int sourceStartBit, int destStartBit, int bitCount)
{
    int[] mask = { 0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255 };
    byte sourceMask = (byte)(mask[bitCount] << (8 - sourceStartBit - bitCount));
    byte destinationMask = (byte)(~(mask[bitCount] << (8-destStartBit - bitCount)));
    byte destinationToCopy = (byte)(destinationByte & destinationMask);
    int diff = destStartBit - sourceStartBit;
    byte sourceToCopy;
    if(diff > 0)
    {
        sourceToCopy = (byte)((sourceByte & sourceMask) >> (diff));
    }
    else
    {
        sourceToCopy = (byte)((sourceByte & sourceMask) << (diff * (-1)));
    }
    return (byte)(sourceToCopy | destinationToCopy);
}
```